# How to generate matched-pairs based on dates?

Tags: r, date, matching

I have a dataset that includes dates and count of reports. I am tasked with generating matched-pairs using these guidelines:

1. Reports will need to be matched to the week immediately prior to or following. (For example: Jan 23, 2000 will be matched with Jan 16, 2000 and Jan 30, 2000)
2. Holidays must not be included in the final matched-pairs generation.

I have been able to identify the holidays within the dataset but am still stuck on how to generate the matched pairs. Any advice would be much appreciated!

[Example of the Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/belPR.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am making assumptions as I could not ask for clarifications.

Assumptions I made

a> You wanted to get a formula bash
b> You wanted the date closest matching the previous week to the specific date. for example a Monday event needed to match closer to an event on Monday the previous week. As the data set you gave showed multiple reports through the week. It was not clear what pattern of the previous week you wanted to match.

Solution based on Assumptions.

1> You can mathematically turn each date to a grouping of which week they were in for the year. Then match them to one another. For example 1/1/2003 would be 1.1. A date in 14/1/2003 would be 2.1.

You can then patten match on if 1.1 = 2.1 if that hits it's a match if not it would loop until it saw an entry in the range of 2.[0-9]. You can place an if statment to check if there is a holiday on the match, if there is one it will continue the loop.